# Disappearing UI jquery

Tags: 2013, jquery

UI accordion, mega-menu and slider banner all disappear for all users with the exception of Site Collection Admins until fully authenticated....is it a user issue or branding?

Code below:

```
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="wssucmui" TagName="MUISelector" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/MUISelector.ascx"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SearchWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="PublishingRibbon" TagName="PublishingRibbon" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Ribbon.ascx"%>

<%@ Register tagprefix="WebControls" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag runat="server" id="SPHtmlTag" dir="&lt;%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%&gt;">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <SharePoint:SPPinnedSiteTile runat="server" TileUrl="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png" TileColor="#0072C6" />
    <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></SharePoint:PageTitle>
    <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
    <SharePoint:StartScript runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15"/>
    <SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />

    <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>


    <!-- ===== STARTER: Core SharePoint CSS =========================================================================================== -->
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />


    <!--CDW Elements-->
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/assets/font-awesome.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/assets/normalize.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/assets/grid.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" /> 

    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/assets/custom.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/assets/layout.css%>" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile" />


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/html5shiv.js'><" + "/script>");</script>
     <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/respond.min.js'><" + "/script>");</script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/jqueryMMD.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/jqueryHoverIntent.min.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/html5lightbox.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/jquery.flexslider.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/jqueryAccordionMenu.js'><" + "/script>");
        document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='/Style Library/assets/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js'><" + "/script>");
    </script>


    <!-- Toggle Code for Nav -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {           
                $('body').addClass('js');
                  var $menu = $('#menu'),
                      $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
                      $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');

                $menulink.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $menulink.toggleClass('active');
                    $menu.toggleClass('active');
                });

                $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
                }); 
        });
    </script>

<!-- Hide Recently Modified -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Recent')").parent().hide();
});
</script>


<!-- JMH:Hide Site Contents -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var t = jQuery(document).find("a[id *= '_idNavLinkViewAll']");
 t.hide();
});
</script>


<!-- Script for Search Submit Button-->
<script type="text/javascript">        
function goSearch()
{                                              
    var searchBox = document.getElementById('search-text');

    window.location = "https://pulse.vrad.com/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=" + searchBox.value;              
    return false;
}

function noenter() 
{
    return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); 
}

function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
    if (default_==null) default_="";
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(qs == null)
    return default_;
    else
    return qs[1];
} 
</script>



<!-- Welcome UserName -->

<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink21" Name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />

<script type= "text/javascript">                                    
    'use strict';
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getUserName();
    });
    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
    function getUserName() {
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
    }
    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    // It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
    function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
         $('#message').text('Welcome, ' + user.get_title());
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }
</script>

    </head>

    <body onhashchange="if (typeof(_spBodyOnHashChange) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnHashChange();">


        <SharePoint:SPClientIDGenerator runat="server" ServerControlID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain;DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea;DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" />
        <SharePoint:ImageLink runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:SharePointForm onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript"> var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; </script>

        <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server"/>     
        <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />   

        <!--- Ribbon -->
        <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon runat="server"/>
        </div>

        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPageStatusBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
            <div id="pageStatusBar"></div>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>


    <div id="s4-workspace">
        <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
            <div class="ms-table" style="width:100%;">  
            <div class="customheader">
                <div class="row ms-dialogHidden">               
                    <div id="s4-titlerow">
                        <div class="grid_6">
                            <div class="customlogo">
                                <a class="brand" href="/">
                                    <img class="max-img vrad" src="/Style Library/assets/logo.png" alt="" />                                
                                </a>                
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid_6">
                            <div class="searchwrapper float-right">
                                <div id="message">Welcome</div>
                                <div id="Search">                               
                                    <div class="btn" data-toggle="button"></div>
                                    <div id="searchLayout">
                                        <input type="text" id="search-text" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) return goSearch();" class="watermark" placeholder="Looking for something?" />
                                        <input type="image" src="/Style%20Library/assets/searchbutton2.png" id="search-submit" alt="Search Button" OnClick="return goSearch();" />          
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                  
                            </div>

                        <!--<div class="navtoggle">
                            <!-- Toggle Link for Nav    
                            <a class="menu-link fa fa-bars" href="#menu" style="display:none"></a>
                        </div>  --> 

                    </div>                                                  
                </div>                  
            </div><!-- Row End -->
        </div> <!-- Custom Header End -->

        <div class="customnav ms-dialogHidden">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <div class="NavWrapper">                    
                        <!-- CDW Global Nav -->
                        <div id="cdwMMD" class="cdwMMDwrapper"></div>               
                        <!-- CDW Global Nav -->
                    </div><!-- NavWrapper End -->       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

    <!-- DeltaPlaceHolderMain Start -->
    <div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">


        <!-- Slider Wrapper -->
        <div class="SliderWrapper" class="ms-dialogHidden">                         
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Slider" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>


        <div class="RowMiddle">
            <div class="row white">
                <div class="grid_3 ms-dialogHidden">


                    <!-- Above SideBar -->
                    <div class="SideNavUpper">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SideBarTop" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                                        
                    </div>

                    <!-- SideBar -->
<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">                    
                    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-navigation ms-noList" role="navigation" runat="server">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">
                                <a name="startNavigation"></a>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                <div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin">
                                    <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager" runat="server" QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu" ContainedControl="QuickLaunch" EnableViewState="false" ><SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">

                                    <Template_Controls>
                                        <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="False" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />
                                    </Template_Controls>

</SharePoint:DelegateControl><SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="3" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="" /></SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
                                        <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager id="TreeViewNavigationManagerV4" runat="server" ContainedControl="TreeView" CssClass="ms-tv-box"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" Text="<%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"
                                            CssClass="ms-tv-header" /><SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TreeViewAndDataSource">


                                                    <Template_Controls>
                                                    <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl runat="server" id="TreeViewDataSourceV4" RootContextObject="Web" IncludeDiscussionFolders="true" />
                                                    <SharePoint:SPRememberScroll runat="server" id="TreeViewRememberScrollV4" onscroll="javascript:_spRecordScrollPositions(this);" style="overflow: auto;">
                                                        <SharePoint:SPTreeView id="WebTreeViewV4" runat="server" ShowLines="false" DataSourceId="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                                            ExpandDepth="0" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tv-selected" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tv-item"
                                                            SkipLinkText="" NodeIndent="12" ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosed.png"
                                                            ExpandImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosedrtl.png"
                                                            CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopen.png"
                                                            CollapseImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopenrtl.png"
                                                            NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvblank.gif" >
                                                        </SharePoint:SPTreeView>
                                                    </SharePoint:SPRememberScroll>
                                                    </Template_Controls>
                                                </SharePoint:DelegateControl></SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server">
                                        <div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
                                            <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton runat="server" id="idNavLinkViewAll" PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                                                NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" Text="<%$Resources:wss,AllSiteContentMore%>"
                                                accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>" CssClass="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" />
                                        </div>
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                    </div>
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
                    </div>
                    <!-- SideBar End -->

                    <!-- Below SideBar -->
                    <div class="SideNavBottom">                         
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SideBarBottom" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- Grid 3 End -->


                <div class="grid_9">

                    <div class="breadcrumbs ms-dialogHidden">
                        <h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">   
                            <!-- ===== STARTER: SP Reqs DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea and PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea for adding Apps in Site Content =================== -->
                            <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">                         
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                    <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider"><PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE><SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
                                        </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE></SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
                                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>                                 

                            <div class="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap">
                                <a href="javascript:;" id="ms-pageDescriptionDiv" style="display:none;">
                                    <span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage">&#160;</span>
                                </a>
                                <span class="ms-accessible" id="ms-pageDescription">
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
                                </span>
                                <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout"); </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
                            </div>
                        </h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="home_breadcrumb">
                        <!-- Add Breadcrumb Path -->
                        <div id="custompagebreadcrumbs">
                            <asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="false" hideinteriorrootnodes="true"></asp:sitemappath>
                        </div>    
                    </div>


                    <!-- Main Content -->
                    <a name="mainContent" tabindex="-1"></a>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>               

                </div><!-- Grid 9 End -->               
            </div><!-- Row End -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- DeltaPlaceHolderMain Start -->



            <!-- Footer -->
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="grid_12">



<WebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart runat="server" ItemStyle="FooterLinks" GroupStyle="DefaultHeader" WebUrl="~sitecollection/" ListGuid="713a7125-dd15-4699-8160-b0784c73307f" ListName="FooterLinks" Filter1ChainingOperator="Or" Filter2ChainingOperator="Or" DataMappingViewFields="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{eb87c873-82ca-442a-b737-5e4033f03c98},Text;{48118f7e-2bed-493c-8a9a-9c7bb426a79e},Choice;{71ead55a-e272-4541-b00d-33f740e27c01},Text;" GroupByDirection="Desc" SortBy="FooterOrder" SortByFieldType="Number" DataMappings="Created:|LinkUrl:|FooterURL:{eb87c873-82ca-442a-b737-5e4033f03c98},FooterURL,Text;|Description:|PubDate:|FileRef:|PublishingPageContent:|TileURL:|FooterTarget:{48118f7e-2bed-493c-8a9a-9c7bb426a79e},FooterTarget,Choice;|ComingSoon:|ImageUrlAltText:|EventDate:|ImageUrl:|Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|VirtualPopupLink:|SliderLink:|onclick:{71ead55a-e272-4541-b00d-33f740e27c01},onclick,Text;|FileSize:|New_Tab_Link:|ArticleStartDate:|TileV:|FileExtension:|" ServerTemplate="100" UseCopyUtil="True" ShowUntargetedItems="False" EnableOriginalValue="False" ViewFlag="0" ViewContentTypeId="" ListId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" NoDefaultStyle="" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" Title="Footer Links" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="Displays a dynamic view of content from your site." IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="ImportedPartZone" PartOrder="0" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_1ab19dc7_67e3_4366_a5a9_633b935ca332" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{1ab19dc7-67e3-4366-a5a9-633b935ca332}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" > <xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /> <xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /> <xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /> </xsl:stylesheet></Xsl>
<SampleData>
<dsQueryResponse>
                    <Rows>
                        <Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True" __begingroup="True" />
                        <Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" />
                    </Rows>
                    </dsQueryResponse></SampleData>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
</WebControls:ContentByQueryWebPart>



                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaFormDigest" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">
                    <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

            <div class="ms-hide">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarBorder" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


            </div>

            <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false" />
            </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--Workspace end-->


    </SharePoint:SharePointForm>
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
        <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">var g_Workspace = "s4-workspace";</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>

    </body>
</SharePoint:SPHtmlTag>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "... until fully authenticated"? Anonymous users cannot access files -- or authenticated users cannot access files unless they are members of the Administrator group?

Comment: We leverage Kerberos windows auth.

Comment: Authorized users cannot access files unless they are members of the administrator group.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `js` & `css` files in the `Style Library` are published and approved.

Comment: They are all checked in.

Comment: @RosalieH. does the user has permission to read those files?

Comment: Yes, all employees have been given permissions to the  library to either read or contribute. I'm not seeing a permission option directly affiliated with the jquery files in the Style Library

Comment: Ok, the data is coming from list/managed terms? Does the users has permissions to those areas?

Comment: That's correct - I have confirmed this as well.

Comment: Everyone has permission level that includes: add items, view items, open items, create alerts, view application pages, view web analytics data, use self-service site creation, view pages, browse user info, use remote interfaces, use client integration features and open

Comment: Checked in is not the same as published, make sure to publish them

Comment: All are checked in and published.

Comment: If I give 'Everyone' site collection admin permissions, have them log in and then revoke the permissions all items are in view.  Site collection admin permissions is the ONLY level that has this desired result.  Obviously opening up the permissions to everyone is not an option.

Comment: If you're using content approval you'll also need to 'approve' the changes to the assets you're using after creating them -- this is in addition to check in and publish.

Comment: Content approval is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you've checked all of content approval/check-in/publishing issues and are still having the same problem I would check one more thing to make sure it's a permissions problem (which is really what it seems to be) -- have a non-admin user attempt to access the asset directly at its url (like `http://yourSPServerUrl/Style%20Library/assets/jquery-1.8.0.min.js`) which should give you a 403 if the issue is permissions related. (if your non-admin user instead sees the jQuery script file contents then you have a different problem...)

If your non-admin users are unable to access the file, then check the permissions on the `Style Library` and make sure your users have Read/View permissions. You can also do something like grant `Everyone` read/view on the `Style Library` since that is really how it's generally used anyway -- but I usually just have mine inherit from the parent site which allows authenticated users to read/view most things (most of my sites are internal-public, and should be viewable for any authenticated user on our windows network)

Comment: The non-admin user is able to access the style library, but when he tried to open a .js file he received a jscript runtime error 'jquery' is undefined.  He is able to open image files from this library however.

Comment: Okay - so not a permissions problem on the assets, I'm still betting it is a permission issue somewhere else in your site though since it works for admins -- authorized permissions are essentially the only difference in SharePoint when a user is an admin. Do normal users have access to the data that populates the UI pieces that are missing? (I'm assuming either a service call or another SharePoint list is where those things live)? You'll need to run down all the other dependent locations (I found an XSL Style Sheets view folder with a quick look.. as 1 example...) and check them too

Comment: Looking at my test user profile I am unable to view site contents via site actions menu at all.  Everything is missing as well as this functionality not working.

Comment: Going in the back end - I was able to confirm that general users cannot access the lists that control the UI components that are missing from view.

Comment: Try adding "`Everyone`" to the Visitor's group (whatever it's called) at your site collection level.

Comment: Already given permission on site collection level.  Same results - no change

Comment: Then make sure all those other lists (where the UI resources are) are inheriting permissions or are also allowing access... the problem is somewhere in those list permissions! May also be worth trying to manually add `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` to the visitor group also (it may not autocomplete properly, but the form should ultimately allow you to enter it)